# how i can use kwargs in django redirect, i have one error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want create a redirect `Django` with kwargs for my detail page.
I have a comment system and I want redirect to the page where the user is inside.

my urls:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from .views import blog, detail, posts_by_tag

app_name = "blog"
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^$',blog, name="blog"),
    re_path('^(?P<year>[\d+]{1,4})/(?P<month>[\d+]{1,2})/(?P<day>[\d+] 
               {1,2})/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', detail, name= "detail"),
    re_path('^(?P<tag>[\w-]+)/$',posts_by_tag, name="tag"),
]
```

my detail :

```
def detail(request, slug, year, month, day):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug,
                                created__year = year,
                                created__month = month,
                                created__day = day)
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.post = post

            new_comment.save()
            return redirect('blog:detail', kwargs= 
{'slug':slug,'created__year':year,'created__month' : month, 
'created__day' : day,})
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    context = {
        'post':post,
        'comments':comments,
        'new_comment':new_comment,
        'comment_form':comment_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', context)
```

my error is :

```
Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'django-python',
  'created__year': '2019', 'created__month': '7', 'created__day': '1'}' not found.
  1 pattern(s) tried:
  ['blog/(?P<year>[\\d+]{1,4})/(?P<month>[\\d+]{1,2})/(?P<day>[\\d+]{1,2})/(?P<slug>[\\w-]+)/$']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs show this in the [examples section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect):

> 2) By passing the name of a view and optionally some positional or
>   keyword arguments; the URL will be reverse resolved using the
>   `reverse()` method:
>
> ```
> def my_view(request):
>     ...
>     return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
> ```

Have you tried this?

```
return redirect('blog:detail', slug=slug, year=year, month=month, day=day)
```

Comment: oh my God ! Thank's